# Trigger function after element load (Typescript/Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, function, events

I want to do something like this:

```
<div (load)="activateFunction($event)">Text</div>
```

it calls a function:

```
  public activateFunction(e: any){
   / / do something
    }
```

but the load event won't work. Is there any way to trigger a function on an specific element when it loads? I thought about using ngOnInit, but since it needs the $event from that specific element I'm not sure if it is possible or how to apply it there.

Comment: load only works on specific things like img where it triggers and event. Since this is a div its static, but if you have it wrapped in a if statement its none static. You could use ViewChild with static false in this case and have the value being set with a property

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple example how you could do it. I am assuming that the div you want to trigger load event on is inside a nested structural directive and hence it not there on ngOnInit().

here is one way to do it.

some.component.html

```
<div #triggerName></div>
```

some.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('triggerName',{static: false})
set trigger(val: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>){
    // do stuff here
}
```

not saying this the correct way to do things. Since you already have something that would trigger the structural div you might as well do it from there. but its a way to do it.

Comment: But how do I get the $event on this example?

Comment: What do you expect from `$event`? What information it could contain?

Comment: @EdmundsFolkmanis the tag, I'll get e.target inside the function

Comment: Why? Property value with `@ViewChild` decorator will be set to target DOM node HTML element or Directive, Component. With setter you can catch the moment when this object is initialized.

Comment: @EdmundsFolkmanis Yes, I'm trying to use ViewChild, but it keeps returning undefined

Comment: Your setter function with `@ViewChild` decorator is called with `undefined` value? Can you provide some code?

Comment: My guess is you are trying to use some package that requires the dom element. on the val: ElementRef<the type> you can call .nativeElement that would be equal to a target on lets stay an pointerevent.target